# Not getting data from api in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to make an api. problem is it does not response value. It shows null. I am using postman. Here I'm keeping json in body with json format. My goal is to show the name when I hit api. Here is data which I am passing

```
{
"username":"xxxx"
}
```

In my api controller

```
public function getName()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $name = $this->request->data('username');
        $val = ["username" => $name];

        $this->response->type('json');
        $this->response->body(json_encode($val));
        return $this->response;

    }
}
```

Comment: Check `Content-type` header is set to `application/json`

Comment: It works for **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** But i want to do it for application/json. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the `POST` data is `null`? Or that the response body is `null`? Or maybe both? If it's the former, or both, then make sure that you have loaded [**the `RequestHandler` component**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html).

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP is still PHP. At the very top of the function, I would do a `pr($_POST);` and see what's coming through. If nothing, are you definitely POSTing? If you do see some data, is it prepended with a model name, or something else, which would cause `$this->request->data('username')` to return `null`? At the very least you can make sure you're actually posting to the right place, and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  It works for **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** But i want to do it for **application/json** in header.

Comment: I see. Do you have a view for this action? I don't think you can just return the value, you need to set it to the view for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

try this (for CakePHP > 3):

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->viewBuilder()->className('Json');

    $name = $this->request->data('username');
    $val = ["username" => $name];

    $this->set(compact('val'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['val']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$input = $this->request->input('json_decode');
pr($input);
```